# Which exception does SMO Transfer Raise?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, smo

While using this code

```
try
{
    transfer.TransferData();
}
catch (SmoException smoex)
{
    //Do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Do something else
}
```

The exception is always caught by the second catch statement.
Does someone know why this happens?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to determine what the exception you get actually is:

```
try
{
   transfer.TransferData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var theRealExceptionTypeName = ex.GetType().Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out and let u know

Comment: TransferException -> using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the exception is not an `SmoException`.

It is either an `Exception` or another exception type deriving from `Exception`, but not `SmoException`.  `SmoException` would be caught by the first handler if it were truely an `SmoException` or a class deriving from `SmoException`.  Hopefully that sentence isn't as confusing to read as it was to type!

Further reading on exceptions and exception handling:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Documentation doesn't say what exceptions are thrown:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer.transferdata.aspx